# How do I get PostgreSQL to recognize repeating dates for a mathematical operation?

Tags: postgresql, date, repeat, percentage

Very new to SQL querying. Using PostgreSQL.

I am trying to build a query that tells me what percentage of the time a unique customer id makes multiple transactions on the same day.

I have a query built that gets me the customer ids and transaction dates (if there are multiple on the same day, the date repeats.

Below is my query..

```
SELECT customer.customer_id, rental_date::date FROM customer
FULL OUTER JOIN rental
ON customer.customer_id = rental.customer_id
FULL OUTER JOIN inventory
ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
FULL OUTER JOIN film
ON inventory.film_id = film.film_id
ORDER BY customer.customer_id, rental_date
```

Update:

Query now reads:

```
SELECT customer.customer_id, rental_date::date, COUNT (*)
  FROM customer
  JOIN rental ON customer.customer_id = rental.customer_id
  JOIN inventory ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
  JOIN film ON inventory.film_id = film.film_id
GROUP BY customer.customer_id, rental_date
ORDER BY customer.customer_id, rental_date
```

Output:

+-------------+-------------+-------+
| customer_id | rental_date | count |
+-------------+-------------+-------+
|           1 | 2005-05-25  |     1 |
|           1 | 2005-05-28  |     1 |
|           1 | 2005-06-15  |     1 |
|           1 | 2005-06-15  |     1 |
|           1 | 2005-06-15  |     1 |
|           2 | 2005-06-16  |     1 |
+-------------+-------------+-------+

Desired output:

+-------------+-------------+-------+
| customer_id | rental_date | count |
+-------------+-------------+-------+
|           1 | 2005-05-25  |     1 |
|           1 | 2005-05-28  |     1 |
|           1 | 2005-06-15  |     3 |
|           2 | 2005-06-16  |     1 |
+-------------+-------------+-------+

Comment: The latest query should have produced the desired output, as the values `| 1 | 2005-06-15 | 1 |`  do in fact constitute a single group, at least visually also that you cast to date on the select column list.  These lead me to think that the data type for rental_date is `timestamp` or `timestamptz`.   Try changing to `group by customer_id, rental_date::date`.

Comment: Since the posted answer lead to a successful solution would you please accept it.  An accepted answer helps future questioners with the same or similar issue. It also removes the question from the unanswered queue. Do not leave answered questions as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `count` and `having`. `Count` will get you the number of purchases by day and `Having` can be used to eliminate those with 0 or 1 purchases on a given day.

```
select customer.customer_id, rental_date, count(*) 
  from customer
  join rental    on customer.customer_id = rental.customer_id
  join inventory on rental.inventory_id  = inventory.inventory_id
  join film      on inventory.film_id    = film.film_id
 group by customer.customer_id, rental_date 
having count(*) > 1
 order by customer.customer_id, rental_date ;
```

Also I doubt you want `full outer join`. That returns all rows from both the joined tables even when none exist in the other. I change it to an inner join (you only want `customer`s that have `rental`s and also `inventory` that  also have `rental`s. Even though now the `having` would eliminate the extras. Try removing the `having` clause then run with both full and again inner joins and see the difference.

Comment: Thanks so much! I am hoping to get it the results to show if a customer made multiple transaction on one day, the count reflects that. For example, my results currently show: 

"customer_id" "rental_date" "count"
21 "2005-05-25" 1
21 "2005-05-26" 1
21 "2005-05-26" 1

Is there a way to tell it to show:

"customer_id" "rental_date" "count"
21 "2005-05-25" 1
21 "2005-05-26" 2

Comment: Please post sample data and the **exact** output you want. Post data from that data  and results as [formatted columnar text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/).  It seem what you are asking is just what the query produces except showing only those customers with more than 1 daily purchase.  Post this as an update (by clicking edit beneath it) to your question, not as another comment.

Comment: Since the posted answer lead to a successful solution would you please accept it.  An accepted answer helps future questioners with the same or similar issue. It also removes the question from the unanswered queue. Don not leave answered questions as unanswered.